# Why is plotLine after redrawing a series in Highcharts not displayed anymore?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i define a `plotLine` for my x axis as in [the example from the official highcharts documentation](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-color/).

as soon as i modify my chart (programmatically or just with two clicks on the series legend to hide and show the series again; try yourself in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-color/)), the vertical plot line is not shown anymore.

is this behaviour as it should be, am i doing something wrong or is this a bug in highcharts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug.

This Stackoverflow question [How to always show the plotLine in HighCharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084849/how-to-always-show-the-plotline-in-highcharts) will have a workable answer for you.

Comment: already read that answer there... but i guess i just got the clue on it when reading it a third time now... thank you!